# order by date for grouped data and aggregate data in R

Tags: r

My dat has different cities & states and weekly level values(1&2).

```
structure(list(city_id = c("IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", "IR130", 
"IR130", "IR130"), state_id = c(333L, 333L, 333L, 
333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 
333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L), 
    weekly_date = structure(c(1517702400, 1527379200, 
    1509235200, 1523145600, 1524960000, 1531612800, 1526774400, 
    1520121600, 1510444800, 1532217600, 1530403200, 1514678400, 
    1529798400, 1512259200, 1506211200, 1508025600, 1513468800, 
    1516492800, 1522540800, 1506816000, 1505606400, 1521936000, 
    1518307200, 1531008000, 1523750400, 1512864000, 1529193600, 
    1511654400, 1511049600, 1515283200, 1517097600, 1519516800, 
    1525564800, 1521331200, 1508630400, 1518912000, 1505001600, 
    1526169600, 1509840000, 1507420800, 1514073600, 1528588800, 
    1520726400, 1515888000, 1524355200, 1527984000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), value_1 = c(0.183820871041667, 
    0.180725895208333, 0.35, 0.200932068125, 0.171669985625, 
    0.225808075208333, 0.198545789791666, 0.189855414375, 0.35, 
    0.277725830833333, 0.201674817708333, 0.35, 0.226923487291666, 
    0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.18633958, 0.35, 0.35, 0.188240067708333, 
    0.189944218125, 0.210746212708333, 0.183896871041667, 0.35, 
    0.211807967291666, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.176269423125, 
    0.171773345833333, 0.185080020416667, 0.35, 0.181930044166667, 
    0.35, 0.184190593541666, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.215020983541666, 
    0.182612662916667, 0.35, 0.186923380833333, 0.211272482916666
    ), value_2 = c(0.160883679767442, 
    0.186424108837209, 0.35, 0.182523738139535, 0.227294089534884, 
    0.487345912857143, 0.167833364418605, 0.458898800697674, 
    0.35, 0.42808395877551, 0.254013390408163, 0.35, 0.25048365122449, 
    0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.350976408139535, 0.35, 0.35, 
    0.42162227, 0.356722947906977, 0.24491883755102, 0.234551652325581, 
    0.35, 0.283487755102041, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.403158770697674, 
    0.273511963488372, 0.423378554186047, 0.35, 0.384183884418605, 
    0.35, 0.346561459069767, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.205802955306122, 
    0.422308468372093, 0.35, 0.20876661744186, 0.330639838372093
    )), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-46L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000000000b7d1ef0>)
```

Am trying below code to group by state,city and then order by date and then aggregate to monthly level data of both value_1 and value_2 but it's not working

```
monthly <- dat   %>%
  group_by(state_id,city_id) %>%
  order_by(weekly_date)%>%
  tq_transmute(select  = c("value_1","value_2")
                           mutate_fun = apply.monthly,
                          FUN        = mean)
```

Can someone help me in R 
EDIT:My final output should be grouped by city and ordered by monthly_data

Comment: `library(tidyverse);
library(lubridate);
df %>%
  group_by(state_id, city_id, month = month(weekly_date)) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean))
`

Comment: There's a typo in Ronak Shah's function above, it's `months(weekly_date)` with an 's' on the end, but otherwise this works well if you want the named month. If you want the months in numbers instead try this: `library(stringr); library(tidyverse); library(lubridate);                             
bdf$month <- bdf$weekly_date %>% 
  stringr::str_extract("(?<=-)[:digit:]{2}(?=-)") %>%
  as.numeric();

bdf %>% 
  group_by(state_id, city_id, month) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean))
`

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I'm having 3 years of weekly data so when I get monthly data I can average again to 3 months data for getting the growth rate of each city.The above code is working but it's showing date in `2018-06-16`  (instead of getting the last day which is present in that month for that year )and also the date column is not in order to calculate the growth rate.Can you help me @Ronak Shah

Comment: monthly <- mydat %>%
  group_by(state_id, city_id, month=month(weekly_date)) %>%
  summarise_at(c("value_1","value_2"), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `month` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable` getting the above error @RendyEzaPutra

Comment: @ddheart code is working but the date columns are not in order.I would like to have them in order to for further calculations like calculating the growth rate for every 3 months

Comment: Compute the above we discussed, store it in some object `df`, and just call `df <- arrange(df, month)` to get what you want. (use `desc(month)` for descending order; note `desc` and `arrange` are dplyr functions).

Comment: If you have more questions, I recommend [R4DS](r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) as a solid reference, and/or editing the content of your post to reflect what you would like help on.

Comment: @ddheart It's working and sorting by month but while ordering by month it's showing `2017-09-20` next to `2018-07-21`. But I need the monthly data that is grouped by city.